# Error only with custom sidebar component using react navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native, and been googling but cant find an answer.

I'm using React Navigation and made a custom sidebar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation'
import { AppRegistry, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Container, Content, Text, List, ListItem } from "native-base";



class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

But whenever I try adding a configuration to the `DrawerNavigation`, I get an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.routeName')`

When I remove `contentComponent` the error goes away.

This is my `Navigator.js` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Platform, View} from 'react-native'
import {
  StackNavigator,
  DrawerNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'
import {colors} from './utils/constants.js'

import { HamburgerIcon } from './components/icons'

import { Sidebar, Navbar } from './components'

import SignUp from './screens/Auth/SignUp'
import AccountType from './screens/Auth/AccountType'
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard'






// BEGIN USER ONBOARDING

const AuthStack = DrawerNavigator({
  SignUp: { 
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      drawerLabel: 'Sign Up',
      headerTitle: 'Sign Up',

    })
  },
  Stage1: { 
    screen: AccountType,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      drawerLabel: 'Account Type',
      headerTitle: 'Account Type',

    }) 
  }
}, {
  contentComponent: props => <Sidebar {...props} />
});


// ONCE USER IS AUTHENTICATED

const MainStack = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: { 
    screen: Dashboard,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerTitle: 'Dashboard',

    }) 
  },
});



// MAIN NAV OUTPUT

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  AuthScreen: { 
    screen: AuthStack,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: () => (<Navbar {...navigation}/>)
    })
  },
  MainFlow: {
    screen: MainStack,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: () => (<Navbar {...navigation}/>)
    })
  }
})

export default Navigation;
```

Based on all the examples, it seems I'm doing things right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug in `react-navigation` at the moment as seen here: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/3148

The workaround until this issue is resolved is to add the following to your drawer configuration:

```
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
```

for example:

```
const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
  Page1: { screen: App },
  Page2: { screen: App2 },
}, {
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#000000',
});
```